# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails" with PayPal's adaptive_payments_samples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Getting the following error while trying to install 'adaptive_payments_samples' gem: https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby/tree/master/samples

I'm not sure what gem I am missing or what dependency problem I should solve.
Did bundle update, but that did not help.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rails (= 4.2.3)

  In Gemfile:
    rails-assets-cdn (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (>= 0) ruby

    rails-assets-cdn (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (>= 0) ruby

    griddler-mandrill (>= 0) ruby depends on
      griddler (>= 1.2.1) ruby depends on
        rails (>= 3.2.0) ruby

    adaptive_payments_samples (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 3.2.9) ruby

    rails (~> 4.2.3) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Comment: adaptive_payments_samples depends on `rails ~> 3.2.9` (which means any rails version higher than or equal to 3.2.9, but lower than 3.3.0). You cannot use a gem locked to `rails < 3.3.0` with rails 4.2.3 . Check to see if there is a newer version of adaptive_payments_samples out

Comment: Thanks AOG. I did not know that it meant "but lower than 3.3.0".